# More route services in php

Tags: php, routes, slim, silex

is theoretically possible use more services for routing?

For example if somebody use Silex and has this code:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->get('/test/{id}', function ($id) {
    // ...
});

$app->run();
```

And i create api using Slim like that:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/api/' . $version . 'something', function () use ($app){
        $data = $app->request->params();
    });

$app->run();
```

How user could implement my API withou rewrite Slim route function to Silex route function?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving a quick though, the way I see it you have 3 options:

### Refactor controller closures to a named function

Both, [Silex](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php#L139) and [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-callbacks)[1] can use any form of callable, so instead of passing a closure just pass a function name (or an array with class name, method name) or any other [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). This way with 1 declaration you'll be able to call it from both Slim and Silex (yes, you have to define the routes on both sides).

This has its drawbacks as the controller signature is different for the 2 frameworks, so you'll need to hook into silex flow and change the parameters (you have the [Kernel.controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-controller) event to do that).

Also you'll need to redefine all your services and use the container wisely (i.e, don't use it as a service locator in your controllers).

This is probably the most inflexible way.

### Define the routes in Silex and instatiate a Slim APP inside to call and return that

You'll need to define the api routes again in Silex and in each route you can try to instatiate the Slim APP (using something as `require "path/to/the/slim/app/php/file.php"`) and then [force the run method with the silent option on](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/App.php#L305)[2]

You'll probably need to refactor your Slim application a bit, you'll have to define your app in a file and call the `run` method in another.

### Create a Silex middleware to handle all the /api/ calls

The easiest (?) way that I can think of is redefine the second option and create a *catch all* incoming request to the /api/ mount point by creating a Silex middleware that checks [for each incoming request](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/middlewares.html#before-middleware) if the request has the /api/ string inside the request. Then you'll simply forawrd the request to the Slim application as I've told you in the second option.

Using this method you don't need to redefine the routes in Silex as everything under the /api/ point will be forwarded to the Slim application.

**NOTE**

In all cases you'll probably need to transform the response given from Slim to a [Symfony response](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#response). Slim 3 uses the new PSR-7 HTTP interface so you have a [solution here already](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/psr7.html). Slim 2 echos the response directly so you'll need to catch that and put it inside a Symfony response (`new Response(ob_get_clean())`

---

[1] This is for the Slim3, Slim2 may also be able to do that but I'm not sure (and the signature is different!)

[2] Again this is for Slim3, Slim2 does not has this option, so you'll need to figure something to get the response (maybe [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php)?)